# Use the custom SPFieldType when adding new column

Tags: sharepoint-2010, splist, spfield

I would like to know how to use the custom SPFieldType (Existing on the Site) when adding new SPList column.

E.g.
[Normal way using the SPFieldType.Text field type]

**list.Fields.Add("Location", SPFieldType.Text, true);

list.Update();**

How about for the custom field type?

**list.Fields.Add("Location", [Custom SPField Type], true);** ?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of [Add](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms472869.aspx), try [AddFieldAsXml](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.spfieldcollection.addfieldasxml.aspx).

For more information, see [Programmatically creating a field (column) from the Custom field type](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/syedi/archive/2009/12/04/programmatically-creating-a-field-column-from-the-custom-field-type-in-wss-3-0-moss.aspx).